# Image on hover appears after hovering over another image, but keep both images next to one another

Tags: html, css, hover, css-position

[[enter image description here]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdPhd.jpg) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1VvX.jpg)

I'm attempting to have it so when the user hovers over a map pin, another image appears next to the pin rather than on top of/over it. So far both images are displaying however when I try to move the image, the map pin moves along with it which I do not want. I tried to do hover after where the map pin stayed in the same position but that didn't work out.
If possible with just CSS/JS only.

```
#map-pin1:hover
{
    background-image: url('img/demon-days.jpg');
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

#map-pin1:hover:after {
    content: url(img/map-pin1);
    display: block;
    top: 90px;
    left: 130px;
}
```

Comment: please add some screenshot of your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Without a screenshot it's hard to tell 100% what you're after, but the `top: 90px` and `left: 130px` won't work unless your `:after` pseudoelement is `position: absolute` - does this work?

```
#map-pin1:hover
{
    background-image: url('img/demon-days.jpg');
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

#map-pin1:hover:after {
    content: url(img/map-pin1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    left: 130px;
}
```